# iOS BarButtonItems functional but not visible in Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

The Navigation Bar is hidden in the first View Controller of the Navigation Controller. From there on it is not, but the Bar Buttons are not visible. They are still tappable and functional, and visible in the Storyboard.

The code worked well at some point and now the issue appeared.

**Found the problem**, it was a barTintColor issue on the UINavigationBar.appearance(), I set a wrong UIColor and didn't even remember. I had it gray over gray

This is the relevant code for the first VC in the Navigation Controller, although I tried other ways to do this:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}
```

From there on the controllers have this code on the viewDidLoad:

```
navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
```

Thank you.

[image: Navigation Bar with no visible Bar Button Items]

Comment: try to set title programatically .

Comment: can you add screen short please?

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya I uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: @KKRocks added a title but it's not visible.

Comment: i hink your navigation bar is hidden try this navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false) or navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya I did, and a few variations of it. The Navigation Bar is showing, I can even tap on the items and they work. They are just not visible.

Comment: Found the problem, it was a barTintColor issue on the UINavigationBar.appearance(), I set a wrong UIColor and didn't even remember. I had it gray over gray.